# ModuleNotFoundError with a installed module

Tags: python, module, modulenotfounderror, playsound, auto-py-to-exe

I have a problem when I try to convert a .py file to .exe. I get the ModuleNotFoundError error, specifically with the playsound module. I've made sure to have it installed (with pip list) and, just in case, I've tried uninstalling it and installing a more stable version following the advice of a forum and it's still the same. The program works perfectly but when converting it to .exe (using auto-py-to-exe) it tells me that it can't find the playsound module. Has anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! The problem was that I had multiple versions of python installed and the modules were conflicting.